# Is there something wrong with the flowchart?

Tags: java, flowchart

Based on the given flowchart, there is no println statement indicated after declaring row+1 and column=1. How do I actually print out the output as shown below. *Flowchart and code listed below.

**Output**

```
**********
**********
**********
**********
```

**Flowchart**

[image]

**Code**

```
int row = 1, column = 1;
    
while (row <= 4) {
    if (column <= 10) {
        System.out.print("*");
        column += 1;
    } else {
        row += 1;
        column = 1;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking what change you need to make to the flowchart?

Comment: If the output you listed is the desired effect then you are missing an 'output' block in your flowchart when you increment the number of the row

Comment: @Joni, I have written the code based on the given flowchart to produce the output as shown above, however i realized that if I did not include the System.out.println(); It will display "**********" instead. Is the flowchart missing the println?

Comment: It certainly does not have `println` but I can't tell you if it's "missing" -- because "missing" would imply that it's supposed to be there and I don't know if it's supposed to be there